# How can we reduce hourly weather forecast to minutely using openweathermap api?

Tags: java, openweathermap, weather-api

Is there any way to reduce hourly weather forecast to minutely update using openweathermap api. As for the testing purpose i want minutely update of weather for the specific city. (P.S. I am working on Java) Thanks

Comment: Try their [support](https://openweathermap.desk.com/customer/portal/emails/new). The "How to Start" section says: "Free and Startup accounts have limitation of capacity and data availability. If you do not get respond from server do not try to repeat your request immediately, but only after 10 min. Also we recommend to store your previous request data. "

Comment: did you find anything related to this topic? i am looking for an api for minute forecasts..

Comment: @EbruGüngör Yes ! you can use DarkSky api for the minutely weather forecast depending on what area you are working. It give 15k api calls per month free.

Comment: @Ahsan when i tried some example calls in darksky api only responded back minutely data for USA and UK. I need minutely data for eastern Europe. Do you know whether they support it with any additional charge or any other requirement?

Comment: @EbruGüngör if you are not getting minutely data for your desired area which is eastern Europe unfortunately that means your weather stations are not providing them that data. You may concern their support and ask them in details regarding this.

Comment: @Ahsan thank you very much for your answers. I will do contact with them.

Comment: @EbruGüngör pleasure ! let me know if you want anymore information :)